# Unit test for AOSP code?

Tags: android

Are unit test cases provided for any app in AOSP(Android Open Source Project)in android? Suppose take Gallery App, which is a system app. If I download the AOSP, Is complete test suite available for Gallery App. I meant to say both unit tests and Instrumentation test suites?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in working with AOSP, there is a python script called runtest.py in [platform development/testrunner/runtest.py](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/testrunner/runtest.py) to run every available unit tests on each module in AOSP. It is a good starting point to look for what you want, but beware some unit tests are outdated and obsoleted.

You can add tests and then be include into runtest.py to form a test suite. runtest.py will help you compile, deploy then run the unit test suite on the target device.

Comment: So Google didn't provide any test suite source code?

Comment: There are some test suites come with AOSP, you should download the source to take a look first.